# how to display months as columns along with min bal in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

For example

```
ID     TID       DATE           BALANCE
1       24     02-11-2018     198
2       2       08-11-2018     199
2       3        05-11-2018    0
4       13     26-11-2018     115
4       14     28-11-2018     113
```

Balance for Nov-18 should be displayed as below

```
ID BALANCE
1     198
2     0
3     0
4     113
```

for id-3, 0 should be displayed since there is no balance for these id in the month of November for id -1,2 & 4 min balance should be displayed.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, where does "3" come from?  It is not in your data at all.  It seems just made up.

Comment: How do you know anything call id-3 exists?

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you want can be obtained by a simple GROUP BY and some date formatting:

```
select a.id,
       date_format(date, '%Y-%m') as month,
       coalesce(min(balance), 0) as min_balance
  from accounts a
  left outer join balances b
    on b.id = a.id
  group by a.id, date_format(date, '%Y-%m')
  order by a.id, date_format(date, '%Y-%m')
```

Here we're using the `date_format` function to extract the year and month from the date value, and then grouping the results by `id` and the formatted date. This produces the result

```
id  month   min_balance
1   2018-11 198
2   2018-11 0
3           0
4   2018-11 113
```

It seems apparent that there must be another table which contains all the account values, so I added a table named `accounts` with these values. Change this if needed.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=36d21980cd42b040b1b8079ebba9f96b)